# What is the correct solution to return one observable issue to two Observable<boolean>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

this function return an observable this.baseAuthentification.canActivate(route, state) and

the function this.haveDroits() return also an observable.

I want to return a observable if this.baseAuthentification.canActivate(route, state) return false. I want to return false but if true i want to return the value of this.haveDroits(). How i can do this by using rxjs.

Thank you and sorry for my english language :s

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the relevant code from your component in the form of a formatted code block? https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is really hard to understand, best what I got from your text:

```
const result$: Observable<boolean> =
  this.baseAuthentification.canActivate(route, state).pipe(
    switchMap(canActivate => canActivate ? this.haveDroits() : of(false)),
  );
```

Comment: Thanck you for your answer, it's working, have a nice day